# How to set Spark job staging location

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

My spark job is failing because the user doesn't have access to directory where spark is trying to write staging or temp dataset.

> 2017-03-10 10:25:47,0928 ERROR JniCommon
>   fs/client/fileclient/cc/jni_MapRClient.cc:2072 Thread: 26413 mkdirs
>   failed for
>   /user/cxpdiprod/.sparkStaging/application_1488190062017_14041, error
>   13 Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User cxpdiprod(user
>   id 99871)  has been denied access to create
>   application_1488190062017_14041
>           at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.makeDir(MapRFileSystem.java:1250)
>           at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.mkdirs(MapRFileSystem.java:1270)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1913)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:634)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:356)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:727)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:142)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1021)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1081)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:742)

The user 'cxpdiprod' has access to some other directory in cluster i.e. `/mapr/ui/abc`. Are there any property to set the different directory for temp and staging files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this property `spark.yarn.stagingDir`  with the desired staging location in `spark-defaults.conf`.  By default, the staging location is current user's home directory `/user/username/` in HDFS filesystem.

Comment: Thanks..I am using mapr cluster and I don't have access to update spark-default.conf  file. As suggested i added addtional parameter to job but it didn't work, i still get same error:--conf "spark.yarn.stagingDir=/mapr/Helios/cxpdi/warehouse" \

Comment: Can you try without the quotes, `--conf spark.yarn.stagingDir=/mapr/Helios/cxpdi/warehouse`. And what is the version of Spark? This property was added very recently [SPARK-13063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13063)

Comment: Specifying spark.yarn.stagingDir is failing to create sparkSession for me. Using spark2.2

Comment: if you add the staging directory like a local path ( --conf spark.yarn.stagingDir=/mapr/Helios/cxpdi/warehouse) it would fail. Use the file system type in the like --conf spark.yarn.stagingDir=hdfs:///mapr/Helios/cxpdi/warehouse. For hdfs HA, you don't need to use the hdfs service name.

Answer (score 3):

One minor update: The staging directory needs to be specified as

```
--conf spark.yarn.stagingDir=hdfs:///<path/to/staging>
```

At least in my cluster I tried without the `hdfs:///` and it didn't work. Adding the `hdfs:///` worked for me.